# Convert website completely in XML to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert the following website into a dataframe so I can work with the data: https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/rss/forums/4-food-safety-quality-discussion/

Everywhere I look online, I only see how to convert XML FILES to dataframes. I've tried the following but it will not work because it is not an XML file. I can do the pandas section myself but first, need to have data to work with.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

r = requests.get("https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/rss/forums/4-food-safety-quality-discussion/",headers=headers)

c = r.content

root = ET.parse(r).getroot()

print(root)
```

What steps am I missing here to get the XML into a readable format to convert the data into a pandas dataframe?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share a full "working" example next time, including imports, and all used variables (headers - in this code snippet as an example)

Comment: Updated, sorry noted for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML you want to parse is an RSS, and because it has a specific format, you can use a python library that parses RSS feeds ([feedparser](https://pypi.org/project/feedparser/) as an example)

```py
import feedparser
import pandas as pd

parsed_rss = feedparser.parse('https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/rss/forums/4-food-safety-quality-discussion/')

pd.DataFrame(parsed_rss['entries'])
                                                title                                       title_detail  ...                                                 id guidislink
0                      Monitored vs Verifying Records  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  ...  https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/topic/38...      False
1   Is it necessary to follow the new ISO 22000 to...  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  ...  https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/topic/38...      False
2                      usda inspector tagging product  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  ...  https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/topic/38...      False
3                              Chocolate Liquor Discs  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  ...  https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/topic/38...      False
4                              Multi-Pack Beef Sticks  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  ...  https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/topic/38...      False
..                                                ...                                                ...  ...                                                ...        ...
95  HACCP Pan for super critical fluid extraction ...  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  ...  https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/topic/38...      False
96               Illegal Drugs Pictured on Food Label  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  ...  https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/topic/38...      False
97    BRC metal can packaging compliance requirements  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  ...  https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/topic/38...      False
98  Codex Decision tree in ISO 22000:2018 - Clause...  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  ...  https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/topic/38...      False
99           BRC clause 4.3.4 - Battery Charging area  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  ...  https://www.ifsqn.com/forum/index.php/topic/38...      False

[100 rows x 10 columns]
```

another method would be to parse the XML yourself to some structure which can be used to construct a DataFrame, [Example here](https://medium.com/@robertopreste/from-xml-to-pandas-dataframes-9292980b1c1c)

Edit:

Now i see that you passed `r` and not `c` in the following line:

```py
root = ET.parse(r).getroot()
```